# Storing data into a structure full of pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a program that is reading a file, but not saving into the structure. Once the data is read, it should be saved within the structure in order for the program to be able to use said data later. I'm having a heck of a time figuring out how to get this done.

structure

```
typedef struct friends_contact {
   char *First_Name;
   char *Last_Name;
   char *home_phone;
   char *cell_phone;
 } fr;
```

Reading of the file

```
void ReadFile(fr *friends, int *counter, char buffer[], FILE *read) {
  fseek(read, 0, SEEK_SET);      
  while (fscanf(read, "%s", buffer) != EOF) {
    friends[*counter].First_Name = malloc(BUFFSIZE * strlen(buffer));
     strcpy(friends[*counter].First_Name, buffer);

  }  

}
```

More information can be provided as needed. I just want to figure out why the information isn't saving within the structure so that it can be called on later.

Comment: Why did you make `counter` a pointer? Also, do you ever use `contacts` in the body of `ReadFile`?

Comment: your save-code will be quite illuminating in answering this question.

Comment: @dtidmarsh sorry that was a type, `contacts` should be `friends`

Comment: He passed counter by address to return how many items were read, most likely. Btw ReadFile is a most-horrid name for a function if you are anywhere *near* a Windows OS.

Comment: @WhozCraig In the past I've had people complain about posting code that is too long, and that they rather have it more to the point. Tell me what you need to see, I have a menu function, and add function, a delete function, a search contacts function, and a show contracts function.

Comment: @user1781966 No worries. It was a subtle hint that the proper mechanics of pulling your data out of your save-file will be literally *directly* related to the precise mechanics with which you saved it. I hope that was a little clearer.

Comment: Are you using any debugging tool? That could help.

Comment: @nairdaen I tried using the debug option on my compiler and it didn't help

Answer (score 4):

What is "friends"? global variable?
What is "contacts"? It is not used in function.
May be you mix them?

`BUFFSIZE * strlen(buffer)` -> What do you mean? you allocate `strlen(buffer)` `BUFFSIZE` times.
Possibly it should be `sizeof(char) * strlen(buffer)` ?

I also think you should check the length of "buffer" after operation `fscanf`.

Comment: The `friends` `contacts` issue was a typo. I have edited the main post.

Answer (score 0):

The code you use for allocating space for the char array and then copying to it makes sense but one of two things could be happening in your `while()` cycle: the condition is evaluated instantly to `false` so nothing is copied or you iterate over and over again until fscanf writes an empty string to buffer and this overwrites the content of `friends[*counter].First_Name`, should you increment `*counter` in the body of `while()`?

Comment: I tried adding the *counter to the body, but it crashes the program

Comment: I could post the entire lengthy code if that would better help you figure out the problem.

Comment: how did you add it (*counter)?